# Why can't i connect to Kafka with PySpark? Getting a cannot find data source 'kafka' error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I am trying to build a real-time big data pipeline with the Lambda-Architecture. I have so far been able to create the data ingestion module with Kafka as well as the Batch-Layer with S3 and Redshift. However I can't seem to connect to my kafka server through PySpark. I am very new at Spark and I've looked for solutions around the Internet, but none seem to deal with the Python environment.

Here is my code:

```
import pyspark as spark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local[*]") \
    .appName("Learning_Spark") \
    .getOrCreate()

data_stream = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
    .option("subscribe", "tweets-lambda1") \
    .option("startingOffsets","latest") \
    .load()
```

The error I'm getting is the following:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o36.load.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide".;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:652)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:161)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AnalysisException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-b77746ac3efc> in <module>
      4     .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
      5     .option("subscribe", "tweets-lambda1") \
----> 6     .option("startingOffsets","latest") \
      7     .load()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\streaming.py in load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
    398             return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))
    399         else:
--> 400             return self._df(self._jreader.load())
    401 
    402     @since(2.0)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     67                                              e.java_exception.getStackTrace()))
     68             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: '):
---> 69                 raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     70             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis'):
     71                 raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)

AnalysisException: 'Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide".;
```

What could be wrong? I haven't been able to solve it by looking at the "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide" since the information there pertains to mostly the Java developing environment. I am sure the config information is right because I am using the same information for the Batch-Layer. Any help would be enormously appreciated!!

Edit: According to the mentioned guide I have tried running the following command. It goes through, but still fail to connect:

```
spark-submit --class "Learning_Spark" --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.0 ...
```

Comment: Please provide spark, kafka, spark-sql-kafka jar versions as well.

Comment: Most probably what's wrong is that you're having a version mismatch.

Comment: Here are the names of the packages I downloaded:

spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7
kafka_2.12-2.3.0
spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.0

Comment: You're using `0-10_2.11:2.3.0` which is a 2.3.0 version

Comment: Thanks for answering. Which version would be appropiate in this case?

Comment: Given your Apache Spark Version,

Please use [Spark-SQL-Kafka 0.10_2.12:2.4.4](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12/2.4.4)

Comment: I tried it and still can't connect. I ran the spark-submit command with the new version and it seemed to install just fine. Should I have removed the older version?

Comment: Check which one it actually uses, see loaded packages.

Comment: Hey I got it to work! You were right. It was a version issue. I got it to run by running pyspark from the terminal with the following command: !pyspark --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.4 . Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Very well. You may delete the question or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the observatoins from the user pissall I was able to solve the issue. It was a version issue. I got it to run by running pyspark from the terminal with the following command:

```
!pyspark --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the tested code for pyspark structured streaming code which is streaming data from Kafka in below stack overflow link.

[Failed to find leader for topics; java.lang.NullPointerException NullPointerException at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.formatAddress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58755063/failed-to-find-leader-for-topics-java-lang-nullpointerexception-nullpointerexce/58860695#58860695)

```
/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/spark2/bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.0,org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.2.0 --conf spark.ui.port=4055 --files /home/bdpda/spark_jaas,/home/bdpda/bdpda.headless.keytab --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/bdpda/spark_jaas" --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/bdpda/spark_jaas" pysparkstructurestreaming.py
```

Note:

1. 01.This code has tested in SSL enabled cluster . If your environment is not SSL enabled cluster you can ignore the SSL related config
   details.
2. --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.0 - This parameter should be adjusted based on the your environment Spark version .